# Characteristic of a field and algebraic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In what way the characteristic of a field influences the curves defined over that field? For example, let $C$ be the curve defined by $X^3+Y^3+Z^3=0$ over an algebraically closed field $K$. What happen to the curve if $char(K)=3$ or $char(K)\ne 3$? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over characteristic $p=3$, $X^3+Y^3+Z^3 = (X+Y+Z)^3$.

Comment: Can you explain why is that true?

Comment: @mip Why not just multiply out the cube and see what happens?

Comment: Oh, I see! Besides $X^3, Y^3$ and $Z^3$, all other terms from the expansion have a coefficient divisible by 3, which mean that they are $0$. Thank you!!